# read long text in android textView (100,000 words)

Tags: android, textview

i'm need to build a book app that show textView when you click on the button (simple app)

the problem is that i have a 100,000 words in this text (fro assets folder)
and the loading is 8 second !! in the newest android phone

i'm reading the text now whith input stream and with get assets

what is the option to read this text with high performance , or should i split the text to many small files?

code:

```
   public String getString(String fileName) {
        String text = "nothing";
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = am.open(fileName);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int tav = is.read();
            while (tav != -1) {
                baos.write(tav);
                tav = is.read();
            }
            text = baos.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            text = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    text = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_rabi_nahman, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a WebView instead of the TextView.